# Python Function doesn't returns correct value while calling from for loop

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Ok guys I have this following Python script

```
myDict = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "c":3
}


def get_ky(val):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        if val == value:
            return key
        else:
            return "no match"


myList = [1,2,3]


for i in myList:
    print(get_ky(i))
```

and got this result

```
a
no match
no match
```

I want to know why it printed correct result at first iteration and "no match" at the consecutive iteration. please help me to understand this. Also this my first question, if I got something wrong please don't kill me.

Comment: Hint: add `print(val, value)` at the beginning of the loop in the function.

Comment: On the very first item, you `return` *something*, either `key` or `"no match"`. You never continue checking further items.

Comment: @matszwecja good idea! I get it now! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The reason why it is not working for you:

**Step 1:** when you pass the `i=1`, then it checks the `1==1`, which is `true` and returns the key `a`

**Step 2:** When you send `i=2`, then it checks the `2==1` which is `false` so it will jump to the `else` block and return **"no match"**(here it will not iterate for other values of the `myDict`)

**Step 2:** Same thing is happening here also like **Step 2**.

So you need to do it this way, if it is not matched after the whole `myDict` then return "**no match**"

```
myDict = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "c":3
}


def get_ky(val):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        if val == value:
            return key
    return "no match"

myList = [1,2,3]

for i in myList:
    print(get_ky(i))
```

***You can also visualize yourself what is happening behind the scene step by step here at*** [pythontutor.com](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=myDict%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22a%22%3A1,%0A%20%20%20%20%22b%22%3A2,%0A%20%20%20%20%22c%22%3A3%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Adef%20get_ky%28val%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20key,%20value%20in%20myDict.items%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28key,%20value,%20val%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20val%20%3D%3D%20value%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20key%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22no%20match%22%0A%0A%0AmyList%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3%5D%0A%0A%0Afor%20i%20in%20myList%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28get_ky%28i%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=3&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) on the for loop:

```
myDict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}


def get_ky(val):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        if val == value:
            return key
    else:
        return "no match"


myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in myList:
    print(get_ky(i))
```

Out:

```
a
b
c
no match
```

Comment: Or just omit the `else` and have a bare `return` statement after the loop…

Comment: this does work. But I want to know why it prints "no match" when I use an else statement

Comment: @Nayan Think about it. Follow your code step by step on http://pythontutor.com if needed.